# Glitch in computing $\int_0^8\frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]x}$?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Why do Wolframalpha and Symbolab say
$$\int_0^8\frac1{\sqrt[3]x}dx=6$$
when the function is not continuous in the given interval?

[image]

Comment: The improper integral converges and equals $\int_\frac12^\infty \frac{dx}{x^3}$. Do you think it diverges?

Comment: Possible answers:  (a) That is the Lebesgue integral ... (b) That is the improper Riemann integral.

Comment: Please, next time, [type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), and choose a more descriptive tite.  I did both for you this time.

Comment: $\int_0^8\frac1{\sqrt[3]x}dx=\left[\frac32x^{2/3}\right]_0^8$.

Comment: Combining what Anne and Greg are saying: the integral from $a$ to $8$ evaluates as $6-\frac{3}{2}a^{2/3}$ so let $a$ become as tiny as you like and you get closer and closer to $6$.

Answer (score 2):

When an integrand is continuous except at the left endpoint of integration, it is an improper integral, and *by definition* it means the quantity
$$
\int_0^8 \frac1{\sqrt[3]x}\,dx = \lim_{a\to0^+} \int_a^8 \frac1{\sqrt[3]x}\,dx.
$$
(The limit might or might not exist.)

Comment: There are plenty of functions that are discontinuous at their left endpoint for which the plain old, not improper, Riemann integral exists.